# Cloudflare Pages Wrangler local proxy returns 404 for SPA

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages, wrangler

I have a Pages Single-Page App (SPA) with a hello world function.  I've got it working on Cloudflare servers.  the `/` route works great. `/api/hello` my function works great and also `/about` which is resolved by my SPA router works fine.

However, when I proxy the tooling to run it locally using `npx wrangler pages dev -- npm start` and try `/about` I get a `404` error. Is this a bug in Wrangler?  It seems it does not recognize this is an SPA and is either trying to find a function or a page. Any settings I'm missing?

Exact Error:

```
404 File Not Found
Url: /about
File: /Users/…/…/…/www/about
```

(using `…` to obfuscate exact directory names)